# how to get instance chat message without press back button in quickblox

Tags: android

I want to get message in my chat activity without press back button in Quickblox instance chat

```
userData = new QBUser();
userData.setEmail(uNameStr);
userData.setPassword(uPwdStr);
userData.setId(user.getId());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set listeners after the   privateChat.sendMessage(chatMessage); so when you get success in listeners call notifydatasetchange method of the adapter.

```
    private void sendMessage() {
//      privateChatManager = chatService.getPrivateChatManager();
        Log.d("PRIVATE", ">>>>> " + privateChatManager);
        Log.d("INST", ">>>>> " + QBChatService.getInstance());
        Log.d("CHAT ", "" + chatService);
        Log.d("PRI", ">>>>> " + QBChatService.getInstance().getPrivateChatManager());

        //login to chat firstly
        if (messageEdt.length() > 0) {
            privateChatMessageListener = new QBMessageListener<QBPrivateChat>() {
                @Override
                public void processMessage(QBPrivateChat privateChat, final QBChatMessage chatMessage) {
                    Log.e("privateChat ", " " + privateChat);
                    Log.e("chatMessage", "" + chatMessage);
                    chatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void processError(QBPrivateChat privateChat, QBChatException error, QBChatMessage originMessage) {
                    Log.e("privateChat ", " " + privateChat);
                    Log.e("QBChatMessage", "" + originMessage);
                    Log.e("error", "" + error);
                }
            };

            privateChatManagerListener = new QBPrivateChatManagerListener() {
                @Override
                public void chatCreated(final QBPrivateChat privateChat, final boolean createdLocally) {
                    if (!createdLocally) {
                        privateChat.addMessageListener(privateChatMessageListener);
                    }
                }
            };

ChattingFragment.chatService.getPrivateChatManager().addPrivateChatManagerListener(privateChatManagerListener);
            try {
                QBChatMessage chatMessage = new QBChatMessage();
                chatMessage.setBody(messageEdt.getText().toString());
                chatMessage.setProperty("save_to_history", "1"); // Save a message to history
                chatMessage.setProperty("notification_type", "1");
                chatMessage.setSenderId(Integer.parseInt(Util.ReadSharePrefrence(getApplicationContext(), Constant.SHRED_PR.KEY_QB_USERID)));
                chatMessage.setRecipientId(opponentId);
                chatMessage.setMarkable(true);
                privateChatManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getPrivateChatManager();
                QBPrivateChat privateChat = privateChatManager.getChat(opponentId);
                if (privateChat == null) {
                    privateChat = privateChatManager.createChat(opponentId, privateChatMessageListener);
                }
                // send message
                privateChat.sendMessage(chatMessage);
                privateChat.addMessageSentListener(privateChatMessageSentListener);
                privateChat.addMessageListener(privateChatMessageListener);


            } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                Toast.makeText(PrivateChat.this, "Exception " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    private QBMessageSentListener<QBPrivateChat> privateChatMessageSentListener = new QBMessageSentListener<QBPrivateChat>() {
        @Override
        public void processMessageSent(QBPrivateChat qbChat, QBChatMessage qbChatMessage) {
            Log.d("MEHUL", "M " + qbChat);
            Log.d("MSG", "MSG " + qbChatMessage);
            hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashmap.put("id", "" + qbChatMessage.getId());
            if (qbChatMessage.getBody() != null) {
                hashmap.put("msg", "" + qbChatMessage.getBody());
            } else {
                hashmap.put("msg", "");
            }
            hashmap.put("recipient_id", "" + opponentId);
            hashmap.put("sender_id", "" + user_id);

            Collection<QBAttachment> collection = qbChatMessage.getAttachments();
            if (collection != null && collection.size() > 0) {
                for (QBAttachment attachment : collection) {
                    String imageid = attachment.getId();
                    String RecivedUrl = attachment.getUrl();
                    hashmap.put("url", "" + RecivedUrl);
                }
                //Here is the AsyncTask where I am trying to download image
                //
            }

            String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

            // textView is the TextView view that should display it
            hashmap.put("updated_at", "" + currentDateTimeString);
            chatArraylist.add(hashmap);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            messageEdt.setText("");

            chatListAdapter = new PrivateChatMsgListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), chatArraylist);
            lvChatDetails.setAdapter(chatListAdapter);
            lvChatDetails.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
            lvChatDetails.setStackFromBottom(true);
            chatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            scrollMyListViewToBottom();
        }

        @Override
        public void processMessageFailed(QBPrivateChat qbChat, QBChatMessage qbChatMessage) {
            Log.d("MEHUL", "M " + qbChat);
            Log.d("MSG", "ERR " + qbChatMessage);
        }
    };
```